# I created virtual environment in my project which git clone by git bash. But my pip isn't working, it's broken

Tags: python, git, pip, git-bash

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in 
load_entry_point('pip==21.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2229, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2235, in resolve
module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-21.0-py3.5.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")

Comment: Please attach the complete error log.

Comment: @hoefling For a few weeks the SyntaxError with `f"ERROR: {exc}"` will be meaning the same thing: old Python (2.7, 3.4 or 3.5).